# Installed via Laravel Sail and available on the port Meilisearch doesn't add indexes for models; date.ms file seems to be missing

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile, laravel-sail, meilisearch

I added Meilisearch to the project, now its interface is available in the browser at :7700 and I see the following in my browser:
[image]

I installed Meilisearch via Laravel Sail utility, below is the content of my docker-compose.yml file:
[image]

And the contents of my .env file, which is related to the Meilisearch configuration:

```
SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:7700
MEILISEARCH_KEY=masterKey
FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT=7700
```

Now I'm trying to add the first index with the command:

```
sail artisan scout:import "App\Models\<model name>"
```

I'm getting an error:

```
 MeiliSearch\Exceptions\CommunicationException 

Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7700: Connection refused for "http://127.0.0.1:7700/indexes/<model name>s/documents?primaryKey=id".
```

**I noticed that there is no data.ms file in the project.** Its appearance indicates that meilisearch has been started. In some docker tutorials I have seen commands like:

```
docker run -p 7700:7700 -v "$(pwd)/data.ms:/data.ms" getmeili/meilisearch"

docker pull getmeili/meilisearch:latest && docker run -it --rm \
        -p 7700:7700 \
        -v $(pwd)/data.ms:/data.ms \
        getmeili/meilisearch:latest
```

... but I don't have a custom docker config, I have Laravel Sail!!!!!

Why is Mailisearch running in a browser and running on the port it's configured on, but I can't see the data.ms file and get an error when I try to add indexes for models? Please help me to understand the problem and fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in incorrect configuration.

It was necessary to replace the host address 127.0.0.1 with value 'meilisearch' in the .env file like this:

```
SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://meilisearch:7700
MEILISEARCH_KEY=masterKey
```

Similarly (but this was not the problem) it was necessary to replace the host address 127.0.0.1 with the value 'meilisearch' in the docker-compose.yml file in 'healthcheck' section like this:

```
healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://meilisearch:7700/health"]
    retries: 3
    timeout: 5s
```